# Web API URI and controller naming & structure

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I am writing my first Web API app and have some questions on proper URI naming and how to structure the controllers.   This is an ecommerce app.

For the orders, I came up with this:

```
Resource                    GET               POST           PUT             DELETE
/api/orders/123             Get order header  Create order   Upd. order  Delete order
/api/orders/123/lines       List lines
/api/orders/123/lines/1     N/U               Create line    Upd. line   Delete line
/api/orders/123/payments    List payments
/api/orders/123/payments/1                    Create paymnt  N/U         Delete paymnt
/api/orders/123/rebates     List rebates
```

**My first question is: is the above a sound naming / URI scheme?**

**My second question is how to best map the URIs above to the proper controller action.**

The order (header) is straight forward:

```
Verb   Resource                  Controller         Action/method
GET    /api/orders/123           OrderController    Get(id)
POST   /api/orders/123           OrderController    Post(Order order)
PUT    /api/orders/123           OrderController    Put(Order order)
DELETE /api/orders/123           OrderController    Delete(id)
```

But how about the order lines - how to name the controller methods?  Like this?

```
Verb   Resource                    Controller         Action/method
GET    /api/orders/123/lines       OrderController    GetLines(id)
POST   /api/orders/123/lines/1     OrderController    PostLine(OrderLine line)
PUT    /api/orders/123/lines/1     OrderController    PutLine(OrderLine line)
DELETE /api/orders/123/lines/1     OrderController    DeleteLine(id)
```

Same question for the payments:

```
Verb   Resource                       Controller         Action/method
GET    /api/orders/123/payments       OrderController    GetPayments(id)
POST   /api/orders/123/payments/1     OrderController    PostPayment(OrderPayment payment)
PUT    /api/orders/123/payments/1     OrderController    PutPayment(OrderPayment payment)
DELETE /api/orders/123/payments/1     OrderController    DeletePayment(id)
```

I am looking for guidance on the above.  A practical & simple solution would be great (even if it bends the RESTfulness a bit).  In other words, I have seen debates regarding what is truly RESTful and what is not, but if breaking a rule gets the job done in a well-structured, workable fashion and keeps things simple, then I have no problems with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure really depends on how you expect clients to use the API and what granularity of access those clients need. For example, if you expect the payments and lines to be updated/read independently of each other, then your API makes sense, but if all clients need to read/modify them together, then you might be going a little overboard with the hierarchy of your paths (you could have just the path representing the individual order rather than subpaths for accessing its component parts).

As for the mapping from path to handler, you will almost always want a unique handler for each path, but you may find that there is a lot of logic in common between the various handlers that can be shared.

Since this is ecommerce, a big part that you should also consider in the design (that is absent here) is how these various different handlers will be authenticated. And which handlers require authentication (and, if so, what level of authentication for the different handlers).

Comment: I am writing the client-side as well (AngularJS).  The lines and payments are in separate grids and are handled independently.  Based on that, do you recommend creating four controllers for my scenario: OrderController, OrderLineController, OrderPaymentController & OrderRebateController?  Regarding authentication, all order-related actions will require authentication in this app.

Comment: It really depends on how similar or dissimilar these views are. What you are proposing seems reasonable, but it's hard to say more without knowing the details of the product that you are building. Without knowing more, though, that seems like a reasonable approach.